# Going crazy with differential backups timeline restore

Tags: sql-server

I am having a hard time trying to find the proper way to do backups so that I could restore to a particular point in time.  I can do a full backup/restore just fine and even restore the very last differential backup, but trying to do anything in between gives me an 'unable to create restore plan due to break in the LSN chain' so I am missing something.

Here is what I do each night at 1am:

```
BACKUP DATABASE MyDatabase TO DISK = @BackupPath
BACKUP LOG MyDatabase TO  DISK = @BackupPath
```

Then, each hour I do this:

```
BACKUP DATABASE MyDatabase TO DISK = @DIFFERENTIALBackupPath  WITH DIFFERENTIAL
BACKUP LOG MyDatabase TO  DISK = @DIFFERENTIALBackupPath
```

I can restore the database at @BackupPath then apply the latest backup from @DIFFERENTIALBackupPath, however, if I try to go back in the timeline to anything other than the latest time, I get that error.  I do see the flags in the timeline that shows where a backup was done.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do the docs answer your question? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-a-sql-server-database-to-a-point-in-time-full-recovery-model?view=sql-server-ver15#TsqlExample

Answer (score 1):

You need to retain *all* the log backups.  You can restore a Full backup, followed by all the Log backups up the point-in-time.  Or you can restore a Full backup, followed by a Differential backup taken at an earlier point-in-time, followed by the Log backups taken after the Differential.

A typical backup sequence might look like:

```
FLLLLLDLLLLLDLLLLLFLLLLLDLLLLLDLLLLLFLLLLLDLLLLLDLLLLL
                ^
                P
```

Valid restore seqeuences to a point-in-time covered by the indicated log backup would be:

```
FLLLLL LLLLL LLL
```

or

```
F           DLLL
```

or

```
F     DLLLLL LLL
```

A Differential backup is only a shortcut to reduce the number of Log backups you need to restore.  You can even start with an *older* Full backup, so long as you have an intact chain of Log backups up to the point-in-time for the restore.

Eg this is a valid restore sequence:

```
FLLLLL LLLLL LLLLL LLLLL LLLLL LLLLL LLLLL LLLLL LLLLL
```

Comment: So I should only be doing log backups each hour vs differential because once I do a differential, I won't be able to go back beyond that?

Comment: No.  The differentials don't prevent anything.  You need the Full backup, and all the log backups.  Optionally you can use a differential to skip over some of the Log backups.

Comment: That's basically what I was thinking which takes me back to the original question.  Since I am doing differential/log backups each hour why do I get the 'LSI' error when trying to go to back to a point of time?

Comment: You can never go backwards to a point-in-time, only forwards.  So you applied a Differential that was _after_ your target point-in-time.